# .htaccess urlrewrite: how to avoid url change?

Tags: .htaccess

I do use that rule in my WordPress

```
RewriteRule  ^modele-(.*)?$ search-auto/?searchModel=$1  [NE,R,L]
```

which works fine : when I type in:

> https://www.sample.com/modele-Renault it redirect to
>   https://www.sample.com/search-auto/?searchModel=Renault

**Is there a way to KEEP the url unchanged in my browser bar ?**

Comment: Just remove `R` flag and make your rule as: `RewriteRule  ^modele-(.*)?$ search-auto/?searchModel=$1  [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: Got a 404 error. Probably because of the ? character that is overwrote as %3F

Comment: Did you try testing in a new browser? If there are more rules then post your full htaccess in question.